# ECL Emma how to handle test resources

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage, emma

i wrote a unit test where i reference to a file which is located in src/test/resources.
The code looks like this:

```
private static final String TEST_FILE = MyClass.class.getResource("").getPath() + "myfile.properties";
```

When i run this test within eclipse with the normal JUnit Runner everything works fine. But when i run this Test with ECL Emma the Test fails.

After some investigations i found out that the execution directory is differend. ECL Emma has its own output folder where it copies all needed ressources and then runs the tests. But it does not copy my test file. I don't know how to fix this. I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use in-place instrumentation like described here:

http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/launching.html

Emma won't affect the classpath/copy the classfiles then.

Another alternative would be to keep you resources in a seperate resources folder (not in src/) and add this folder to the classpath.

And maybe it would be better to retrieve the File as an InputStream:

```
  InputStream inStream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/myfile.properties");
```